# Defining intents and entities in RASA

Tags: rasa

What is the correct way of defining intents and entities in RASA NLU data?

```
  - intent: inform
    
       examples: |
    
    my name is [ny_name](name)
```

or

```
- intent: inform

my name is [my_name](name)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest update of Rasa (which is currently 2.x), you should be using the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the intent should be of type-1. Also, be mindful of the indentation, it is very important & if anything misaligns then you will get error while execution of the bot. Attached is the example intent screenshot.

[image: Example intent]